# WPF PriorityBinding and MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to mix and PriorityBinding MultiBinding in WPF?

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <PriorityBinding TargetNullValue="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
      <Binding Path="Client.Address.PoBox" />
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
        <Binding Path="Client.Address.Street.Name" />
        <Binding Path="Client.Address.Street.Number" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </PriorityBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Is it not quicker to just add this to your code and find out? You're not showing evidence of much research into your problem!

Comment: Maybe you can use that project https://github.com/itabaev/wpf-nestedbinding That project enable support of nested bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.bindings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you cannot:

> PriorityBinding currently supports only objects of type Binding and
>   not MultiBinding or PriorityBinding.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what the documentation says. I missed that paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Priority Binding accepts only Binding type of objects and not MultiBinding. So I dont think it is possible.